# Deserialization Exception in Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to send message to a Kafka Topic with Key as String and value as Double and Send It into another Kafka Topic Using Kafka Streams
The command I used to produce message into Kafka Topic

`kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --property "key.separator=-" --property "parse.key=true"`

The command I used to consume messages from Kafka Topic

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --from-beginning -property "key.separator= - " --property "print.key=true"`

My Kafka Streams Application is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Properties  properties = new Properties(); 
       properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-app");    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

            KStream<String, Double> inputTopic = builder.stream("a-topic",   Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Double()));
            inputTopic.print(Printed.toSysOut());

                
            inputTopic.to("b-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));
            inputTopic.print(Printed.toSysOut());
            Topology topology = builder.build();
            KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology,properties);
            kafkaStreams.start();
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> kafkaStreams.close()));

        
}
```

I also Tried by Specifying the value serializer while producing a message :

`bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic your_topic_name --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --property  "value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.DoubleSerializer"`

The Error I am getting is :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by Deserializer is not 8
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.DoubleDeserializer.deserialize(DoubleDeserializer.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.DoubleDeserializer.deserialize(DoubleDeserializer.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:305)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:984)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1591)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:985)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:762)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:613)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:575)
14:19:43.085 [test-app-efdaea2c-faab-49e9-a371-c9109d0cc96c-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams -- stream-client [test-app-efdaea2c-faab-49e9-a371-c9109d0cc96c] Encountered the following exception during processing and the registered exception handler opted to SHUTDOWN_CLIENT. The streams client is going to shut down now.
```

The data I am trying to send looks like this :

Test:12.34

Test2:123.454

Test3:12345.321

- But When I tried to  change the  Serdes.Double() to Serdes.String()

  ```
  KStream<String, Double> inputTopic = builder.stream("a-topic",   Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));
  ```
- Also When I tried to change the Serdes.Double() to Serdes.String() in Produced With , Then I am Not getting any Errors
- ```
  inputTopic.to("b-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
  ```

[The error I am getting is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLvYW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The command I used to produce message into Kafka Topic

Console producer defaults to serialize data as strings, which is why String Serde / deserializer would work.

Clear the topic and start over with the appropriate producer settings

You could also write a separate runnable producer class rather than use the console tools